# vba selenium find element in dialog role

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
<div id="j_idt249" class="ui-confirm-dialog ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-hidden-container ui-dialog-rtl" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="j_idt249_title" aria-hidden="false" aria-live="polite" style="width: auto; height: auto; left: 385px; top: 265px; z-index: 1022; display: block;">
```

```
<button id="j_idt250" name="j_idt250" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ui-confirmdialog-yes" type="button"><span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-check"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Save</span>
```

Button is inside of div.
How can i click the button

```
bot.FindElementByName("j_idt250").Click
```

its not work.
its something like dialog alert.i atached that pic.[Pic of site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAmYi.png)

Comment: What is the error ?

Answer (score 0):

If the 'id' is available in an element, always use that. If not, go for the other locating strategies. In your case, the Id is present. So, use it when locating.

```
bot.FindElementByName("j_idt250").Click
```

If this won't work, then check the DOM and check whether your element is within an iFrame or not. If there is an iFrame, you need to switch to that iFrame first and then click on the button.

Comment: its not work , how can i switch in that dialog role?

Comment: Try these options

https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/window-handle-in-selenium/

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute looks dynamic and will not be a reliable web element locator.

Instead it looks like a save button.

```
//button[text()='Save']
```

**Code :**

```
bot.FindElementByXpath("//button[contains(text(),'Save')]").Click
```

Comment: its not work dear. this is in a      <div id="j_idt249"     role="dialog"  >  is this for that?

Comment: @RuzbehAdibi : Do you know about developer tool -> element section ? if yes can you share HTML of that pop up or model window ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try switching to Alert like this

```vb
driver.SwitchToAlert.Accept
```